# Showing Contactlist using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-recyclerview

I am displaying contacts from phone in listview using below code, which is working fine.

```
public class ContactList extends ListActivity {
    ListView contactlist;
    Cursor cursor1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_list);

        cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor1);

        String [] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};
        int [] to = { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};

        SimpleCursorAdapter listadAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, cursor1, from, to);
        setListAdapter(listadAdapter);
        contactlist = getListView();
        contactlist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        contactlist.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSelectedItemId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getSelectedItemId();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

now I want to show it using recyclerview, untill now i am adding some string to my recyclerview using below code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<String> myDataset ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        myDataset = new ArrayList<String>();
        myDataset.add("A");
        myDataset.add("B");
        myDataset.add("C");
        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }...
}
```

which is showing me as below
[image]

can anyone guide, the recommended and genuine way to do this task.

thnx

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 1:** Fowlow those step:
1. Create activity layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

2. Create layout for each item view

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/icon"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
       android:contentDescription="TODO"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/secondLine"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="26dip"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
       android:ellipsize="marquee"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:text="Description"
       android:textSize="12sp" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/firstLine"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:text="Example application"
       android:textSize="16sp" />
   ```
3. Create Adapter just like other adapter

   ```
   public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {         

       private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
       // Provide a reference to the views for each data item   
       // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and you provide 
       //access to all the views for a data item in a view holder   
       public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       // each data item is just a string in this case
       public TextView txtHeader;
       public TextView txtFooter;

       public ViewHolder(View v) {
           super(v);
           txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
           txtFooter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
       }   

       public void add(int position, String item) {
           mDataset.add(position, item);
           notifyItemInserted(position);   
       }

       public void remove(String item) {
           int position = mDataset.indexOf(item);
           mDataset.remove(position);
           notifyItemRemoved(position);   
       }
       // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)  
       public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> myDataset) {
           mDataset = myDataset;   
       }

       // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)   
       @Override  
       public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
           // create a new view
           View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout,parent, false);
           // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
           ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
           return vh;   
       }

       // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)  
       @Override   
       public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
           // - get element from your dataset at this position
           // - replace the contents of the view with that element
           final String name = mDataset.get(position);
           holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
           holder.txtHeader.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                       remove(name);
                   }
               });

               holder.txtFooter.setText("Footer: " + mDataset.get(position)); 
       }

       // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)  
       @Override   
       public int getItemCount() {
           return mDataset.size();   
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create activity to link them all together

   public class MyActivity extends Activity {
       private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
       private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
       private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
       mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

       // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
       // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
       mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

       // use a linear layout manager
       mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

       // specify an adapter (see also next example)
       mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   }
   ```

   }

See [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html). that all you need!

Comment: FYI anyone looking at this code, ViewHolder class is missing a } right after the constructor. The closing } is also missing for the MyAdapter class.